# When does a JavaFX program call the start method?

Tags: java, javafx

I am learning JavaFX. And I can only see a launch(args) method in main method. When I a debug into the launch. I can't see any statement call the start().So when does the JavaFX program call the start method?
This is the launch(args) source code.

```
    public static void launch(String... args) {
    // Figure out the right class to call
    StackTraceElement[] cause = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    boolean foundThisMethod = false;
    String callingClassName = null;
    for (StackTraceElement se : cause) {
        // Skip entries until we get to the entry for this class
        String className = se.getClassName();
        String methodName = se.getMethodName();
        if (foundThisMethod) {
            callingClassName = className;
            break;
        } else if (Application.class.getName().equals(className)
                && "launch".equals(methodName)) {

            foundThisMethod = true;
        }
    }

    if (callingClassName == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: unable to determine Application class");
    }

    try {
        Class theClass = Class.forName(callingClassName, true,
                           Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        if (Application.class.isAssignableFrom(theClass)) {
            Class<? extends Application> appClass = theClass;
            LauncherImpl.launchApplication(appClass, args);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + theClass
                    + " is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application");
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only been vaguely familiar with JavaFX, I would guess that the `launch` method is placing an event onto the event queue that will call `start`, so that `start` is guaranteed to be called within the context of it's gui thread...what ever JavaFX calls it...

Comment: Have you looked at `LauncherImpl.launchApplication()` down in the try/catch block?

Comment: yeah,I tried and it stopped at                                               
            launchLatch.await();

Comment: @deathlee That means that there's another thread doing the work somewhere.... Wonder what thread that is.

Answer (score 7):

`LauncherImpl` calls `Application#start`, but does so by placing the actuall call onto the JavaFX event queue via `PlatformImpl.runAndWait`.  This is done after the `Preloader` is launched

`Application#launch` calls `LauncherImpl.launchApplication`, which creates a `Thread` and calls `launchApplication1`, `launchApplication` then waits for this `Thread` to terminate, via a `CountDownLatch`.

This `Thread` then calls `LauncherImpl.launchApplication1`, which launches the `Preloader`, if specified, then, based on a number decisions about the state of the `Preloader` calls `Application#start`, wrapped in a `runAndWait` call, to ensure that `start` is called within the context of the JavaFX's GUI/Event Queue thread...

This is based on Java 8

**Updated...**

`theApp.start`, called by `LauncherImpl.launcherApplication1` is the instance of your `Application`.

`Application` does a look up for your classes name, by walking a `StackTrace`...of all things...

```
StackTraceElement[] cause = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

boolean foundThisMethod = false;
String callingClassName = null;
for (StackTraceElement se : cause) {
    // Skip entries until we get to the entry for this class
    String className = se.getClassName();
    String methodName = se.getMethodName();
    if (foundThisMethod) {
        callingClassName = className;
        break;
    } else if (Application.class.getName().equals(className)
            && "launch".equals(methodName)) {

        foundThisMethod = true;
    }
}
```

This gets the name of your class, it then creates a `Class` instance using `Class.forName` and passes this to `LauncherImpl`...

`launcherApplication1` then constructs a new instance of this class and assigns it to the reference `theApp`, which is an instance of your `Application`

```
PlatformImpl.runAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                Constructor<? extends Application> c = appClass.getConstructor();
                app.set(c.newInstance());
                // Set startup parameters
                ParametersImpl.registerParameters(app.get(), new ParametersImpl(args));
                PlatformImpl.setApplicationName(appClass);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.err.println("Exception in Application constructor");
                constructorError = t;
                error = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
final Application theApp = app.get();
```

It then proceeds to call `theApp.start`, which is calling your `Application`'s `start` method....I know weird, but there it is

Answer (score 4):

JavaFX programs require neither a `main()` method nor for the [Application.launch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-) method to be invoked.

You can remove the `main()` method from your application and the [java application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) will directly invoke the `init()` (on the launcher thread) and `start()` (on the JavaFX application thread) methods on the application.  When you do this, the whole `LauncherImpl` process discussed in some of the other threads (together with its weird determination of the class to be launched via a StackTrace lookup), is skipped.

See the related Java Enhancement Proposal [JEP 153: "Enhance the java command-line launcher to launch JavaFX applications."](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/153) and its accompanying issue tracker link [JDK-8001533 "java launcher must launch javafx applications"](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8001533).

Of course, if you do have a `main()` method in addition to a `start()` method, then the code will currently go down the path outlined by MadProgrammer in his answer.

When writing a JavaFX program, it is probably best to assume that `main()` is never called (though in reality, if you're not deploying as an applet, it is likely `main()` will be called just to stop people getting completely confused).

This process is also described in the [Application javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-):

> The Java launcher loads and initializes the specified Application
>   class on the JavaFX Application Thread. If there is no main method in
>   the Application class, or if the main method calls
>   Application.launch(), then an instance of the Application is then
>   constructed on the JavaFX Application Thread.

Answer (score 2):

At time of posting, the source code for `LauncherImpl` is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/LauncherImpl.java), and line 837 invokes the `start(...)` method. It's pretty grim that far down in the source code...

Comment: Yeah, it is grim and my teacher told me to not care about it. But I am just curious...

Comment: Your teacher is right. There's a point where you assume they know what they are doing and have implemented it correctly... :)

Comment: It also appears at line 755, but it depend on the use and state of the `Preloader`...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. In the vast majority of cases there isn't a preloader (one of those good ideas that assumed we'd figure out the whole web deployment thing and make it work...), so all that code is skipped in all but a few cases.

Answer (score 1):

To add to MadProgrammer's answer:

`Application.class`, line 241:

```
public static void launch(String... args) {
    //...
        if (Application.class.isAssignableFrom(theClass)) {
            Class<? extends Application> appClass = theClass;
            LauncherImpl.launchApplication(appClass, args); // <-- This is where the application is launched

    //...
}
```

Which goes to here (line 118 of `LauncherImpl.class`):

```
public static void launchApplication(final Class<? extends Application> appClass,
        final String[] args) {
    launchApplication(appClass, savedPreloaderClass, args);
}
```

Which goes here (line 158):

```
public static void launchApplication(final Class<? extends Application> appClass,
        final Class<? extends Preloader> preloaderClass,
        final String[] args) {
    //.......
    Thread launcherThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                launchApplication1(appClass, preloaderClass, args); // <-- go here
            } catch (RuntimeException rte) {
    //....
}
```

Which goes to a loooong method on line 674:

```
private static void launchApplication1(final Class<? extends Application> appClass,
        final Class<? extends Preloader> preloaderClass,
        final String[] args) throws Exception {
    //... Lots of stuff 
    // Eventually, on line 755:
    currentPreloader.start(primaryStage);

    // More things for cases where the previous start() call isn't appropriate
    // Line 773:
    final AtomicReference<Application> app = new AtomicReference<>();
    // Line 790/791:
    Constructor<? extends Application> c = appClass.getConstructor(); // Gets constructor for your class
    app.set(c.newInstance()); // Creates a new instance of your class
    // Line 803:
    final Application theApp = app.get();
    // Line 837:
    theApp.start(primaryStage);
}
```

Because your JavaFX project extends `Application`, `appClass` *should* be the class object for your JavaFX project, and so the `start()` method you defined will be called by `theApp.start()`.

Skipped a lot of things, as the source is *much* too long to be posted here, but that's the basic chain of calls

Comment: I just saw the statement, and I found what the statement"theApp.start(primaryStage);" invokes is the start() method in Application. I still don't figure out when does the program invoke the start() method in my own class. Sorry to ask so late because I just found it.

Comment: @deathlee Ah, I see. I'll do some more digging.

Comment: @deathlee `launchApplication1`, constructs a new instance of your `Application` class and assigns it to `theApp`, therefore, `theApp.start` is when JavaFX calls your application's `start` method...

Comment: @deathlee Updated my answer with a bit more specifics, but MadProgrammer pretty much covered it. Your class extends `Application`, so the `start()` method you defined will be called.

Answer (score 0):

also just learning JavaFx, i am under the impression it is just initialized with your class, as it is a method above your main argument.  I am currently working with a simple class that only holds a main argument and the start method, with no other commands and the start method seems to be executed upon compile regardless, but it should be called on

```
launch(args);
```

that is the entirety of my main argument and this is how the start method is executed for me